# Interface extended in a inner Interface, Compilation Error in Jenkins

Tags: java, generics, interface, compiler-errors

I have 2 Interfaces

```
package com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.widget;
import com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.IPresenter;

public interface IDisplay<D> {
   void setPresenter(IPresenter<D> presenter);
   IPresenter<D> getPresenter();
}
```

And

```
package com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.widget.dialogs;

import com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.widget.IDisplay;

public interface IDialogDisplay extends IDisplay<IDialogDisplay> {}
```

Finally I have a class with an Inner Interface

```
package com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.clusterlist;

import com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.dialogs.DialogPresenter;
import com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.widget.dialogs.IDialogDisplay;

public ClusterInPresenter extends DialogPresenter<ClusterInPresenter.ClusterInDisplay> {
  interface ClusterInDisplay extends IDialogDisplay {}

  public ClusterInPresenter(ClusterInDisplay display) {
    super(display)
  }
}
```

Now if I leave it like this the compiler in jenkins fails with a `"Cannot Find Symbol"` for `IDialogDisplay` (on the line of the inner interface declaration). When I use the full IDisplay path like so:

```
package com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.clusterlist;
import com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.dialogs.DialogPresenter;

public ClusterInPresenter extends DialogPresenter<ClusterInPresenter.ClusterInDisplay> {
  interface ClusterInDisplay extends com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.widget.dialogs.IDialogDisplay {}

  public ClusterInPresenter(ClusterInDisplay display) {
    super(display)
  }
}
```

It will compile in jenkins

**Edit:**
full error from jenkins log

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/gfroud/.jenkins/jobs/1View4/workspace/src/main/java/com/oneviewservices/oneview/client/presenter/clusterlist/ClusterListInFileSelectPresenter.java:[25,43] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IDialogDisplay
location: class com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.clusterlist.ClusterListInFileSelectPresenter
[ERROR] /home/gfroud/.jenkins/jobs/1View4/workspace/src/main/java/com/oneviewservices/oneview/client/widget/clusterlist/dialogs/ClusterListInFileSelectDialog.java:[195,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/gfroud/.jenkins/jobs/1View4/workspace/src/main/java/com/oneviewservices/oneview/client/widget/clusterlist/dialogs/ClusterListInFileSelectDialog.java:[203,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/gfroud/.jenkins/jobs/1View4/workspace/src/main/java/com/oneviewservices/oneview/client/widget/clusterlist/dialogs/ClusterListInFileSelectDialog.java:[209,1] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/gfroud/.jenkins/jobs/1View4/workspace/src/main/java/com/oneviewservices/oneview/client/presenter/clusterlist/ClusterListInFileSelectPresenter.java:[23,102] type parameter com.oneviewservices.oneview.client.presenter.clusterlist.ClusterListInFileSelectPresenter.ClusterInDisplay is not within its bound
```

My Question is:

**Why do I have to use the full path for that interface instead importing it like normal?**

Any resources on the subject would be useful.

Comment: Because you forgot to import it? Show us real, complete code, and the exact and complete error message.

Comment: I definitely import everything correctly. I have updated my question with more detail. This all works correctly in eclipse it is jenkins that it fails except changing to resolve the full path. Thank you for your time

Comment: What packages are all these classes and interfaces in?

Comment: updated the question with packages